# Is there a way to increase the reliability and quality of electronics by create custom electronics?

Tags: electrical, hvac, materials

I want reliable electronics for my capmer. I don't want to buy any electronics for home usage, becouse it has a very limited shelf life, as well as certain operating conditions. In a camper, these devices break more often due to harmful environment.

I also believe that electronics sellers need to make money, and want to make a lot of money. So device must be overpriced. And I would like to pay this money not for advertising and marketing, but to a specialist who will make my life better.

So I thought, I can choose higher-quality (in my opinion) reliable components and materials, and pay a specialist, who will make this electronics for the requirements of my camper.

**Can such an approach improve quality and reliability of electronics, or maybe I'm on the wrong way, and there are no better and cheaper devices, than those already sold in the store?**

I also consider the possibility that it might be cheaper and easier to constantly buy new devices than to fix old ones or make them too reliable.

Examples of devices I would like to create: air heater, water heater, clothes dryer, kettle, air purifier, cam security system system, electric door locks, various lighting etc.

Comment: Most of those examples you mentioned do not need electronics, just manual switches and electricity.  Hard to find these days, but old style types last almost 20 years.

Comment: The problem with your idea is that custom-made equipment will be much more expensive. This is because mass-produced stuff is so much less expensive to build than one-offs that you will pay much more even without the middleman markup.

Comment: A part that costs pennies if you're buying 10,000 may cost dollars if you're buying 10.

Comment: You could always scrounge enough money to buy a company like Haier (upwards of $33 billion enterprise value as of today) that makes most of what you’ve listed. It might only take getting majority of the shares. Then, you can get their engineering departments to build things that last better. I think this route would be cheaper and easier than trying to go it alone and recruit all the talent involved to create these devices.

Comment: The air purifiers, electronic door locks and lighting are all things you can DIY, or at least things that I have personally DIYd, which leads me to think others could as well; i'm not special, just motivated, frugal, picky, and tenacious...

Comment: @dandavis Agreed that DIY solutions are possible in most cases, but doing one-off solution yourself vs finding a contract manufacturer able to make something more reliable than you can find mass produced as a one-off product while assuming liability if it burns down your house for all of the listed products in the question… I still think buying a major corporation who does all those things would be the way to go if your not able to DIY.

Comment: You might this discussion interesting. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475555/how-to-design-electronics-to-last-40-years-or-more/475569#475569

Comment: Appliances like those, sounds like you're living in the camper.  The #VanLife culture has a huge quality problem because of being cheap. They love to buy off eBay and Amazon Marketplace, so they get no-name Chinee diesel heaters instead of Dickenson furnaces. They get KOONRX "brand" solar charge controller off Amazon instead of Morningstar. So #VanLife people tend to reject quality, deeming Dickenson and Morningstar a "ripoff".  That is an irreconcilable values conflict and that's that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to ask, the answer is that all you can do is buy commercial components designed for this environment by reputable manufacturers. You are not going to be able to do better design for the combination of robustness, features/performance, and price than they can; from what you've said, I'm guessing you don't have the skills, and probably can't afford completely custom work.

Even if you had the skills, the cost would be significantly higher when considering the value of the time and effort you'd spend on the project.

There are people who can and do go that far, either doing the work themselves or commissioning it... but they're the people for whom the fun of the project, and the bragging rights, and the specific features they can build in which would not be commercially viable, are worth enough to offset the fact that it isn't economically reasonable. It's justified as artwork/hobby rather than on the arguments you've advanced.

Possible? Sure. Practical? Probably not. Good idea? Not if you have to ask.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on the other (excellent, +1) answer:

*commercial components designed for this environment by reputable manufacturers*

This is really the key. For many products, including electronics, electrical components, and mechanical items there are multiple grades available. But they *all* benefit tremendously (except perhaps the very top semi-custom/artisan level) from mass production. Take a simple example - the basic duplex receptacle. Every house has dozens of them, so builders go for the least expensive. But professionals or serious DIYers who appreciate quality will go a step or two up. And in some environments (e.g., hospitals) even higher quality is justifiable due to safety concerns.

Examples here from Home Depot, but the basic principle will apply no matter where you buy, and applies to varying degrees for much larger items like the appliances you listed.

- 15A Residential Grade $0.99 (~ $0.70 in 10 packs)
- 15A Commercial Grade $2.00
- 15A Hospital Grade/Extra Heavy Duty $5.61
- 15A Industrial Grade $7.18

All of these do the same basic thing. All are UL or ETL listed. Some add more features, but the big difference is overall quality. Would I bother with Hospital or Industrial for ordinary use? No. Would I spend the extra $ for commercial grade? Absolutely!

On the other hand, if you (hypothetically - don't do this!) asked an electrical engineer to build you some receptacles from scratch, they would certainly cost a lot more than $7.18 each.

It is a little harder to figure out with more complex devices. To some degree you can tell from the warranty - the longer the warranty the longer the manufacturer *expects* the device to last. But that isn't an absolute as often devices designed for commercial use will have a shorter warranty than devices designed for residential use for a bunch of practical and marketing reasons.

That's not to say there isn't a place for custom-built systems. They just aren't cost effective in most situations *if there is a commercial, mass-produced, alternative*.